# How to relate two django models that are saved by the same form

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

on the frontsite of my new project I have a form that modifies 2 Django models. In fact, the user has to enter his email, name, a personal goal and a deadline for that goal. "email" and "name" belong to the model "User" while the other two belong to the model "Goal".

I am trying to give the Goal a relation(ForeignKey) to belong to the user but I am unable to do it. I know how to do it if there is a user already existing but in my situation the user and the goal(that belongs to him) are created at the same time.

My View looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Goal, User
from .forms import GoalForm, UserForm


def front_site(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        goal_form = GoalForm(request.POST)
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if all([goal_form.is_valid(), user_form.is_valid()]):
            user_form.save()
            goal_form.save()
            return render(request, 'goalapp/single_goal.html',  {'user_form': user_form, 'goal_form': goal_form})
        else:
            user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
            goal_form = GoalForm(request.POST)
            return render(request, 'goalapp/front_site.html',  {'user_form': user_form, 'goal_form': goal_form})
    else:
        goal_form = GoalForm()
        user_form = UserForm()
        return render(request, 'goalapp/front_site.html',  {'user_form': user_form, 'goal_form': goal_form})
```

My Models look like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class User(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user_email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

class Goal(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('goalapp.User', related_name='goal',    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    goal_body = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    goal_deadline = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    goal_status = models.IntegerField(default = 1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.goal_body
```

How do I get this to work so that the ForeignKey will be set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the goal instance by saving the form with commit=False.

```
user = user_form.save()
goal = goal_form.save(commit=False)
goal.user = user
goal.save()
```

Comment: Ah that commit=false does it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just get the user id when saved and assign to Goal

```
 user = user_form.save()
 goal.user = user
 goal_form.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
This gives me a name Error "goal is not defined" ?
I suppose "goal" is addressing the Model Goal? If wirte it in uppercase it does not throw an error but in djangos adminpanel it still does not sho a set foreign key?